# webpack stuck at 95% emitting / ng build --aot --watch

Tags: angular, webpack

In my Angular 5 application I'm using `ng build --aot --watch` to build application and watch any changes in code. Unfortunately usually after second, third save on file - webpack just stuck with message: `95% emitting` and I have to cancel terminal and do it again.

I've found workaround `ng build --aot --watch --sourcemaps=false` although with that I'm not able to debug typescript in Explorer. So this solution isn't perfect.

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: are you getting `memory out of heap`?

Comment: IDE: Visual Studio Code. @Aravind what you mean?

Comment: are you getting any error if you have 95% emitting and `javascript heap out of memory` ?

Comment: No, just stuck in terminal at `95% emitting`

Comment: Webpack needs a lot of time. A complete AOT build needs ~5 Minutes on my system without a lot of modules or components. Also, i found that there was a bug related to `--watch` bug this should be solved by now (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2511).

Comment: Any reason why you are not just using `ng serve`?

Comment: What's your angular-cli version?

Comment: I've got the same issue on CLI version 6.0.0. Can build only without of `sourceMap` or `optimization`, otherwise it's stuck at 95% forever.

Comment: @RaulA. Check my answer.

Comment: @DiPix thanks but that's not helpful for me, I run `ng serve` for development and needed to build with these options for staging however I worked around it by building with `sourceMap:false`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when using the AoT flag, you should also use the other flags provided automatically with [--prod](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds)(except for maybe the environment, you can override that).  Particularly, in your case you may want to look into --sourcemaps=false as this will drastically reduce your build time, but it will remove the source maps, making debugging harder.  Though if you are doing an AoT build usually you are looking for the reduced size for a prod build.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution. 
Just use `ng build --watch` but before that download plugin for Google Chrome - **Disable Content-Security-Policy**. It allows you to work without any problem :)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden

Answer (score 0):

`--sourcemap` halt build in any @angular/cli version 1.7.x, but 1.6.8 works fine, so you can use `@angular/cli@1.6.8` to solve issue with hanging webpack. This is angular 5 issue, but on angular cli v6 also this problem not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem every time that I run `ng build`

The problem was that I mapped the `outputPath` (inside the `angular.json` file) to a network drive (to make the deployment faster and easier) but due to a problem, the drive wasn't mapped.

After I deleted the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again, I got a nice message instead of this problem.

I hope that it will help someone